# How to generate javascript from Java POJO model classes

Tags: javascript, java, gradle

For my microservice implementation I use POJOs with no implementation to serve as model classes for the service API. Is there a library that can be used to generate javascript POJOs from the JAVA POJOs so that I can use them in my Angular javascript clients? The ideal tool could be invoked from my project's gradle and package the generated javascript into a package consumable by jabascript environment (e.g. npm).

Answer (score 1):

So far my research suggests jsweet and the jsweet-gradle-plugin as what will solve my problem nicely:

https://github.com/lgrignon/jsweet-gradle-plugin